# печать в алфавитном порядке всех букв текста (текст оканчивается точкой), входящий в него не более двух раз

Tags: python, list

есть такой код:

```
s = str(input())
letters = []

sortedLetters,orderOfLetters = [],''
letters = sorted([letter.lower() for letter in s if letter.isalpha()])
[sortedLetters.append(letter) for letter in letters if letter not in sortedLetters]

for letter in sortedLetters:
    orderOfLetters = orderOfLetters + letter
print(orderOfLetters + ".")
```

не совсем понимаю как работают тут строки:

```
letters = sorted([letter.lower() for letter in s if letter.isalpha()])
[sortedLetters.append(letter) for letter in letters if letter not in sortedLetters]
```

хотелось бы написать нормальным циклом, но ничего не получается

Answer (score 2):

```
s = str(input())
letters = []

orderOfLetters = ''

letters = []
for letter in s:
    if letter.isalpha():
        letters.append(letter.lower())
letters.sort()

sortedLetters = []
for letter in letters:
    if letter not in sortedLetters:
        sortedLetters.append(letter)

for letter in sortedLetters:
    orderOfLetters = orderOfLetters + letter
print(orderOfLetters + ".")
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: не могли бы вы помочь с этим генератором?

Comment: rez = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]

Comment: `rez = []
for i in range(len(m[0])):
 for j in range(len(m)):
  rez.append(m[j][i])`

Comment: @Dragon если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как принятый и проголосовать "за".